# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](http://fitness.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Deadlift and Rack Lifts](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14953/deadlift-and-rack-lifts)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Sample Regimen for losing body fat and retaining lean mass](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14917/sample-regimen-for-losing-body-fat-and-retaining-lean-mass)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's a good intermediate/advanced squat routine?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/whats-a-good-intermediate-advanced-squat-routine)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to correct bad sleep posture](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-to-correct-bad-sleep-posture)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Weight gaining diet for vegetarian](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/weight-gaining-diet-for-vegetarian)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [On weight loss diet while lifting](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15022/on-weight-loss-diet-while-lifting)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to keep a specific rhythm during sets?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14877/how-to-keep-a-specific-rhythm-during-sets)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What is a recommended way to get a custom work out regimen designed?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14826/what-is-a-recommended-way-to-get-a-custom-work-out-regimen-designed)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Water dripping from nose after swimming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15014/water-dripping-from-nose-after-swimming)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [How to gain height after 21 years?(am racewalker)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14890/how-to-gain-height-after-21-yearsam-racewalker)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 7)

---